# Connect to, or as an HID device using CoreBluetooth

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, bluetooth, hid

Using the `CoreBluetooth` libs, is it possible to scan and connect to HID devices like mice and keyboards?

Also, is it possible to act as a HID device?

I've tried to scan all available bluetooth devices using:

```
[self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
```

But it didn't list any HID devices.

I tried to act as a HID device using the UUID of a HID device, but when I ran a scan with my computer it didn't find it.

```
[[CBMutableService alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:HID_UDID] primary:YES];
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It should be possible. But is your device using Bluetooth Low Energy or just "classical" Bluetooth?

Comment: BTLE and bluetooth classic both supports HID profile but with different implementation.

Comment: I'm using the MacBook Retina to scan for devices and it didn't find it. And in the app that scans for devices, I'm trying to scan for the Apple Bluetooth keyboard, and it didn't find it. Don't these both support BTLE?

Comment: Here's a list of all BTLE compatible devices: http://www.bluetooth.com/Pages/Bluetooth-Smart-Devices-List.aspx

Comment: Apple's BT keyboard is not BTLE, it is a regular BT HID device.